# pom.xml selecting profile from multiple profiles

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml

I have a application with multiple build profiles all stated in my pom.xml, I have something like this below.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sit</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>uat</id>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

how do I now specify, during running,  i want to use sit or uat profile? when it compiles and run, how does spring boot decide which profile to pick?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the active profile name in application properties or at the command line while staring the application with `--spring.profiles.active=sit`

Please check this for more information https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html